# PHP DB2 insert into IBM iSeries where one of the iSeries variables has a # sign

Tags: php, sql, db2-400

I am using the db2 database extention to create a prepared sql statement used for inserting data into an IBM iSeries. The problem I am having is one of the variable names on the iSeries side contains a # (pound sign/ hash). So the code should look like this, assuming # was a valid character in php. How do I get around this?

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO RS63F.PN850HP1 (HTYPE, HFILE, MAILID, HBEG03,HVEND#) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';    
$conn = db2_connect($dB, $user, $pass);
$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);


db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, "HTYPE", DB2_PARAM_IN);
db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, "HFILE", DB2_PARAM_IN);
db2_bind_param($stmt, 3, "orderID", DB2_PARAM_IN);
db2_bind_param($stmt, 4, "orderName", DB2_PARAM_IN);
db2_bind_param($stmt, 5, "custID", DB2_PARAM_IN);

if (db2_execute($stmt)) {
    ECHO("SUCCESS");
};
```

The physical file has 59 variables and I only need to use 5 of them so I was hoping to use this method of insertion.

Comment: Try enclosing it with backticks ?

Comment: Thank you, It looks like that is going to work. I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appologize,

This was actually a sublime text 2 issue. 
Sublime Text 2 made it look as if the # was commenting out the rest of the line. However that was not the case, I was able to leave the code the way it was and run it and it worked fine.